# Is there a way to satisfy some interface based on enum field?

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

I'm trying to make a generic function which will return me an exact interface based on enum argument, but any attempts fails.

Maybe I'm missed something or doing it just wrong?

If I typecast result to that interface everything is ok but it actually somewhat useless for me.

```
enum Commands {
    Info = "info",
    Echo = "echo",
}

interface BaseRequest {
    command: Commands;
    timestamp: number;
}

interface InfoRequest extends BaseRequest {
    command: Commands.Info;
}

interface EchoRequest extends BaseRequest {
    command: Commands.Echo;
}

type GenericRequest = InfoRequest | EchoRequest;

const createRequest = (command: Commands) => ({
    command,
    timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
});

const sendRequest = (request: GenericRequest) => {};

const request = createRequest(Commands.Info);
sendRequest(request);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two solutions:

1. Replace `GenericRequest` with `BaseRequest` in the `sendRequest` function, remove the `GenericRequest` type.
2. Make `createRequest` generic:

   ```
   const createRequest = <TCommand extends Commands>(command: TCommand) => ({
       command,
       timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
   });
   ```

   Thus the `command` property will be of such type that you will pass in the `command` argument.

The explanation is that `createRequest` returns an object with `command` property of the whole type `Commands` regardless of the passed type. And `GenericRequest` type in `sendRequest` defines that the `command` property should be either of the `InfoRequest` or `EchoRequest` type - it doesn't know about all `Command` enum values.